# Java Bytebuffer overwrite bytes

Tags: java, buffer, byte

I've got a `ByteBuffer` that contains 1024 bytes.

I need to overwrite a short within the buffer at a certain offset at key times.

I know the ByteBuffer class has `putShort()`, but this doesn't overwrite the data, it simply adds it in, which is causing buffer overflows.

I'm guessing that there isn't a direct way of doing this using the `ByteBuffer`, can someone possibly suggest a way to do this?

Thanks

Thanks to everyone that replied, seemed it could be done I was just using the wrong version of putShort().  I guess that's what happens when you stare at the same piece of code for six hours.

Thanks again

Comment: `ByteBuffer` has two `putShort` methods: [`putShort(short value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putShort(short)) and [`putShort(int index, short value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putShort(int,%20short)). Are you sure you are using the right one?

Comment: I was totally using the wrong one!  Thanks Mark, problem solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cannot reproduce the problem, all seems OK

```
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(20);
    bb.putShort(10, (short)0xffff);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bb.array()));
```

prints

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

For your special case, you can modify directly the `backing array` using the [array()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array%28%29) method.

Then just insert your two bytes at the proper indexes:

```
if(myBuffer.hasArray()) {
    byte[] array = myBuffer.array();
    array[index] = (byte) (myShort & 0xff);
    array[index + 1] = (byte) ((myShort >> 8) & 0xff);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int p = b.position();
b.position( ZePlace );
p.putShort( ZeValue );
b.position( p );
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position%28%29

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call this version of [putShort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putShort%28int,%20short%29) that accepts a possition index.